# How can I unload a command inside a cog discordpy?

Tags: python, command, discord.py

I made a *Discord Bot* but lately, I have been compiling commands from specific categories into a single cog. How can I unload a specific COMMAND inside a COG without unloading the whole cog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Bot.remove_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.remove_command).  If your command has aliases, you'll need to call it for each of them individually.